# Azure RM Template. Change vNet's DNS Server without deleting subnets

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-rm-template

I'm creating an ARM template will deploy a variable amount of Backup Domain Controllers to existing Virtual Networks. I need to change DNS Servers of existing Virtual Networks. The problem is that my Virtual Networks have completely different subnets from each other, and when I deploy the following resource, existing subnets disappear. How can I only change DNS Servers property of the Virtual Network, without affecting other properties?

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('existingVnetname')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "UpdateVNetDNS2"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "ConfiguringBDCloop"
      ],
      "condition": "[parameters('deployBackupDCs')]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[parameters('existingVnetAddressRange')]"
          ]
        },
        "dhcpOptions": {
          "dnsServers": "[take(variables('privateIParray'),variables('DNSref'))]"
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('existingSubnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('existingSubnetAddressRange')]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
]
```

I know that I can specify existing subnets, but I have a lot of Virtual Networks with completely different subnet names and address ranges, specifying them via parameters would be a nightmare.

Comment: We ended up updating DNS Servers of Virtual Networks with PowerShell script instead of this ARM Template deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I currently use one template for multiple environments with one Virtual Network resource to create multiple vNets by looping through different Configs.

The Parameters contain the vNet prefixes and subnet prefixes for those vNets. For example:

```
"virtualNetworkPrefixHub": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
        "description": "Specify the Virtual Network Prefix for the Hub vNet to create or to be used"
    },
    "allowedValues": [
        "192.168.0.0/25",
        "192.168.32.0/25",
        "192.168.56.0/25",
        "192.168.64.0/25",
        "192.168.96.0/25",
        "192.168.120.0/25"
    ]
},
"virtualNetworkPrefixMgmt": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
        "description": "Specify the Virtual Network Prefix for the Mgmt vNet to create or to be used"
    },
    "allowedValues": [
        "192.168.0.128/25",
        "192.168.32.128/25",
        "192.168.56.128/25",
        "192.168.64.128/25",
        "192.168.96.128/25",
        "192.168.120.128/25"
    ]
},
"subnet0PrefixHub": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
        "description": "Specify the the Subnet Prefix for the wan Subnet in the Hub vNet"
    },
    "allowedValues": [
        "192.168.0.0/27",
        "192.168.32.0/27",
        "192.168.56.0/27",
        "192.168.64.0/27",
        "192.168.96.0/27",
        "192.168.120.0/27"
    ]
},
"subnet1PrefixHub": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
        "description": "Specify the the Subnet Prefix for the lan Subnet in the Hub vNet"
    },
    "allowedValues": [
        "192.168.0.32/27",
        "192.168.32.32/27",
        "192.168.56.32/27",
        "192.168.64.32/27",
        "192.168.96.32/27",
        "192.168.120.32/27"
    ]
},
"subnet0PrefixMgmt": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
        "description": "Specify the the Subnet Prefix for the adds Subnet in the Mgmt vNet"
    },
    "allowedValues": [
        "192.168.0.128/28",
        "192.168.32.128/28",
        "192.168.56.128/28",
        "192.168.64.128/28",
        "192.168.96.128/28",
        "192.168.120.128/28"
    ]
},
"subnet1PrefixMgmt": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
        "description": "Specify the the Subnet Prefix for the Build Subnet in the Mgmt vNet"
    },
    "allowedValues": [
        "192.168.0.144/28",
        "192.168.32.144/28",
        "192.168.56.144/28",
        "192.168.64.144/28",
        "192.168.96.144/28",
        "192.168.120.144/28"
    ],
    "defaultValue": ""
}
```

I define an array of configs per vNet as a complex variable. This where you would define the DNS Servers for the appropriate vNets e.g.

```
"vnet-settings": [
    {
        "name": "[concat('vn-hub')]",
        "dnsServers": "[variables('dnsServers')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "prefix": "[parameters('virtualNetworkPrefixHub')]",
        "subnets": [
            {
                "name": "oob",
                "properties": {
                    "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet0PrefixHub')]"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "GatewaySubnet",
                "properties": {
                    "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet1PrefixHub')]"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "[concat('vn-mgmt')]",
        "dnsServers": "[variables('dnsServers')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "prefix": "[parameters('virtualNetworkPrefixMgmt')]",
        "subnets": [
            {
                "name": "adds",
                "properties": {
                    "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet0PrefixMgmt')]"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "build",
                "properties": {
                    "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet1PrefixMgmt')]"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The Virtual Network Resource looks like:

```
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "[variables('vnet-settings')[copyIndex()].name]",
        "copy": {
            "name": "vnetLoop",
            "count": "[length(variables('vnet-settings'))]"
        },
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
        "location": "[variables('vnet-settings')[copyIndex()].location]",
        "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
        "dependsOn": [],
        "tags": {
            "displayName": "virtualNetworks"
        },
        "properties": {
            "addressSpace": {
                "addressPrefixes": [
                    "[variables('vnet-settings')[copyIndex()].prefix]"
                ]
            },
            "dhcpOptions": {
                "dnsServers": "[variables('vnet-settings')[copyIndex()].dnsServers]"
            },
            "subnets": "[variables('vnet-settings')[copyIndex()].subnets]"
        }
    }
]
```

Hope this helps.

PT.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work for my case. Virtual Networks already exist with different subnet amount, names and addresses.

Comment: Yep - I understood that from your post. The second piece of code allows you to define multiple vNet configs in the one ARM Template and specify the config required, including the different subnets and DNS servers.

Comment: Yep - I understood that from your post. The second piece of code I've supplied allows you to define multiple vNet configs in the one ARM Template, including the different subnets and DNS servers. The nature of ARM Templates is if something hasn't changed, it is ignored. If something has changed i.e. DNS Servers, then only DNS Servers will change. In your case define the vNet configs, the subnets for each and the DNS Servers as per your configured in the Variable 'vnet-settings' is I have done. Deploy the template and the appropriate contig will be applied/changed accordingly.

Comment: You recommend "define the vNet configs, the subnets for each and the DNS Servers as per your configured", but as I stated before defining subnets is not an option.